# How to use Windows credentials to connect remote desktop

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication, python-requests

In my Python script I want to connect to remote server every time. So how can I use my windows credentials to connect to server without typing user ID and password.

By default it should read the userid/password from local system and will connect to remote server.

I tried with getuser() and getpass() but I have to enter the password everytime. I don't want to enter the password it should take automatically from local system password.

Any suggestions..

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry this is not exactly an answer but I have looked on the web and I do not think you can write a code to automatically open Remote desktop without you having to enter the credentials but can you please edit the question so that I can see the code?